# Initial set up with TFS and VS Code on Windows with TEE-CLC

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

The reason why I'm using TEE CLC is because I'm trying to avoid downloading VS Community as I will be developing for work purposes. I was following this video [Set up and Configure the TEE CLC on Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNaEIVZfr0)   but I got stuck after accepting the eula (2:43).

When I enter the command:

```
C:\...\TEE-CLC-14.0.3\tf.cmd workspaces -collection:http://[...]/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

I got the error message:

```
No workspace matching *;[my name] on computer [computer name] found in Team Foundation Server http://[...]/tfs/DefaultCollection.
```

Since I was able to accept the **eula**, I believe I am mapping to the right folder? I read in similar questions that it's a mapping issue. Am I misunderstanding? Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What's the issue? The video shows the same message after accepting the EULA.

Comment: No it doesn't? When the video starts the "workspaces -collection:..." command there is a request to log in with his credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a error message, but a response to your command. At 4:02 in the video, after running `export TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=1`, the command won't ask login any more. If you don't get login request, it mean your credential has been saved.

You could create a workspace first to see whether `tf workspaces` could list it:

```
tf workspace -new my_workspace
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried again today and it started to work. I'm not stuck on getting the tf command to be recognized in the terminal, but I think I'll submit another question for that.